# Why does this simple use of ng-init with delete give a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This simple snippet ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)):

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-init="foo={a: 20}; delete foo['a']">
</div>
```

Creates this  [syntax error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/%24parse/syntax?p0=foo&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=21&p3=foo%3D%7Ba%3A%2020%7D%3B%20delete%20foo%5B%27a%27%5D&p4=foo%5B%27a%27%5D) in both FF and Chrome. Why?

> Syntax Error: Token 'foo' is an unexpected token at column 21 of the expression [foo={a: 20}; delete foo['a']] starting at [foo['a']].

It doesn't matter whether I try `delete foo['a']` or `delete foo.a` - both work in vanilla javascript; neither work in `ng-init`.

Comment: I believe it expects to be able to evaluate the contents of ng-init you can have ng-init call a function which does execute multiple statements.

Comment: @shaunhusain: I don't think it has anything to do with multiple statements. `ng-init="foo={a: 20}; foo.b=34;"` *does* work. I agree that moving the delete to a function will make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently [`ngInit`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) wants an [expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), which is a subset of JS understood by AngularJS parser.

> Expressions are **JavaScript-like** code snippets that are usually placed in bindings such as `{{ expression }}`. **Expressions are processed by the `$parse` service.** Expressions are often post processed using filters to create a more user-friendly format.
>
> **It might be tempting to think of Angular view expressions as JavaScript expressions**, but that is not entirely correct, since Angular **does not use a JavaScript `eval()`** to evaluate expressions.

(emphasis mine)

So `delete` is not supported by `$parse`.

Also, `ngInit` docs say:

> The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, **you should use controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.**